# Service worker is working even the code is Correct in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I need a sample example of the service worker in Aurelia. I tried multiple code examples but no one was invoking the install, activate and fetch methods.

The service worker gets activated, but never got to the point where install is working or activated.

I need some help to understand the main issue.
Also I noticed that addEventListener "load" to the window is not responding therefore I used "aurelia-composed".

service-worker.js

```
// installing & Activating & fetching 

    self.addEventListener("install", event => {
      console.log("====> service worker is installed ", event);

        })
      );
    });

    self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
      console.log(" ====> service worker is activated", event);
    });
    self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
      console.log("====> service worker is fetched ", event);
    });
```

index.ejs

```
// placing the service worker in HTML

    <script>

        if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
          console.log("<== service worker supported ==>");

          window.addEventListener("aurelia-composed", () => {
            console.log("#### window loaded ######");
            navigator.serviceWorker
              .register("./service-worker.js")
              .then(reg => {
                console.log(" ++++  SW registered +++++++",reg);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(` error in registering worker`,err);    

              });
          });
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: if you are using webpack, this plugin might help: https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 3):

there are two things I can observe for this issue:
1) Make sure the service-worker.js is outside the 'src' folder (where aurelia scans code). The service worker code must be a plain js file and must not be bundled.
Also, there is a potential syntax error in the service-worker.js file. Attached goes my own version:

```
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
  console.log("====> service worker is installed ", event);

});

self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
  console.log(" ====> service worker is activated", event);
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  console.log("====> service worker is fetched ", event);
});
```

2) The loading of the service worker file can be put at the end of the main.ts or main.js aurelia file, after the app is run:

```
    await aurelia.start();
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        .then(function (registration) { return registration.update(); })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
    return aurelia.setRoot('app');
```

After doing all this, in my chrome console:

[image]

And voilá!

Best regards.